# Focus on input fires both 'focus' and 'select' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm writing a Javascript script tightly bounded to events. I must execute some instructions on 'focus' event, and some different instructions on 'select' event.
With my surprise I see that giving focus programmatically, fires 'select' event too! That's a big problem.

Can you tell me why this is happening, and if I can block select event programmatically only when I give focus programmatically?

See the following example. When clicking to 'Give focus' button, console will write 'You selected something'!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input id="field" type="text" />
        <a href="#" id="btn">Give focus</a>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#field').on('select', function(e) {
                console.log('You selected something');
            });
            $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
                $('#field').focus();
            })
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i think, both the events are work same, `select` or `click`. Once fire `focus()`, it automatically fire the `select` event. I think no need of 2 events. Only `click ` is sufficient i think.

Comment: That's not the point. I need two different listener on two different events. I must do something on "select" event e something different on "click" event. So i need both of them. The problem is avoinding messing up two events.

Comment: Let us consider you need 2 different event for different purpose. But to select the input field, you need to click it. Hence it will fire 2 events at a time `select` as well as `click`. This is my understanding.

Comment: You're right.. as far as I select by a click.. But I'm giving focus through Javascript, via focus() method. So there is no click...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#field').on('select', function(e) {
            console.log('You selected something');
        });
        $('#btn').click( function(e) {
       
            $('#field').focus();
        })
    });
```

```html
 <input id="field" type="text" />
    <a href="#" id="btn">Give focus</a>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not change anything